# KMP Preprocessing Function

Tags: preprocessor, string-matching, prefix, knuth-morris-pratt

this is the pseudo code I've see in ItoA:

```
1 m = P.length
2 let pi[1...m] be a new array
3 pi[1] = 0
4 k=0
5 for q=2 to m
6    while k > 0 and P[k+1] != P[q]
7       k = pi[k]    
8    if P[k+1] == P[q]
9       k = k+1    
10   pi[q] = k
11 return pi
```

my doubt is why on line 6 we do `k = pi[k]` instead of `k--` which seems to me that should be the way of checking a preffix of length `k` (because if `P[k+1] != P[q]` it means that a preffix of lenght `k+1` that's also suffix cannot be achieved) which can be also suffix, that is comparing with `P[q]`, I also think that if we do it, the running time will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call `k = pi[k]` searches for the smaller *border* of `p[1..q]`; because the `pi[k]`, which is the largest border of `P[0..k]`, is smaller border of `p[1..q]` than `pi[q]`. It will search until it finds a border of `p[1..q]` where the next character `p[k+1]` is not equal to `P[q+1]`.

You can find more details here: http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/kmpen.htm